# Find the value of $S$, sum of some Harmonic Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Find the value of $$S=\sum_{t=1}^{37}t\left(\frac1{t}+\frac1{t+1}+\frac1{t+2}+\cdots+\frac1{37}\right)$$

This question was asked in an exam which I took. I thought that converting it to a compact form will help me solve the summation. I tried converting it to a double summation but in vain. Which ever technique I used, nothing was of any help. Then I thought maybe Harmonic Numbers can help. I rewrote the problem as $$S=\sum_{t=1}^{37}t\left(H_{t-1}\right)$$ This looks like an Arithmetic Geometric Progression but it's not, rather it's a Arithmetic Harmonic Progression (if that's a thing). I'm stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like something that might be able to be done using a telescoping series, did you try that?

Comment: @wjmccann no...I couldn't think of a way to apply telescopic here

Comment: It should be $S = \sum_{t = 1}^{37} t (H_{37} - H_{t-1})$ so what you really want to evaluate is $ \sum_{t = 1}^{37} t H_{t-1}$, which is close to what you wrote but not quite the same.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks...I am editing jt

Comment: So there's the property $\sum_{k=1}^n H_k = (n+1)H_n - n$ (you can prove it, for example, by induction or via the recursive definition of the harmonic numbers). I imagine your sum should fall to this identity after summation by parts. This seems like quite the hard problem for an exam though.

Comment: just for clarification, on this exam were you provided access to a calculator, or did they want you to explicitly evaluate this in terms of an exact rational

Comment: @wjmccann no calculator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us try "converting it to a double summation". $$\begin{aligned}S&=\sum_{t=1}^{37}\sum_{j=t}^{37}\frac tj\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{37}\sum_{t=1}^{j}\frac tj\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{37}\frac{j(j+1)}{2j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{37}\frac{j+1}2\\
&=\frac{37\cdot40}{2\cdot2}\\
&=370
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 6):

Expansion of my comment.

First recall (or prove) the easy identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n H_k = (n+1)H_n - n \tag{1}$$
We now want to calculate
$\sum_{k=1}^n k (H_n -H_{k-1})$ (where $H(0)=0$) where $n = 37$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^n k H_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}H_n$, our problem reduces to calculating $\sum_{k=1}^n k H_{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1) H_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kH_k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} H_k$.

Note $(1)$ applies directly to the second sum, so we now need to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kH_k$. Via [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), this is the same as:
$$H_{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k-\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}(H_{j+1}-H_{j})\sum_{k=1}^{j}k$$
which reduces to
$$H_{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k-\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{j+1}\sum_{k=1}^{j}k$$
Note the rightmost sum nicely yields a factor of $j+1$ to kill the denominator, leaving an answer of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kH_k = H_{n-1}\frac{\left(n-1\right)n}{2}-\frac{\left(n-2\right)\left(n-1\right)}{4}$$

Now putting everything together and collecting harmonic number terms, we find:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k (H_n -H_{k-1}) = \frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}H_n-\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}H_{n-1}+\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{4}$$

This can be simplified further; using the fact $H_m - H_{m-1} = \frac{1}{m}$, this reduces further to:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k (H_n -H_{k-1}) = \frac{n+1}{2}+\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{4}$$
which finally simplifies to:
$$\color{red}{\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^n k (H_n -H_{k-1}) = \frac{1}{4}n\left(n+3\right)}}$$

---

In particular, the answer to the original question is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{37} k (H_{37} -H_{k-1}) = \frac{1}{4}(37)(40) = 370$$

Comment: Ah ya beat me to it haha, nice work!

Answer (score 4):

**Official Solution**

$$S=1\left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{37}\right)+2\left(\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{37}\right)+\cdots+36\left(\frac1{36}+\frac1{37}\right)+37\left(\frac1{37}\right)$$
$$\implies S=1(1)+\frac12(1+2)+\frac13(1+2+3)+\cdots+\frac1{37}(1+2+3+\cdots+37)$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{t=1}^{37}\frac1{t}(1+2+3+\cdots+t)$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{t=1}^{37}\frac{t(t+1)}{2t}$$
$$\implies S=\frac12\sum_{t=1}^{37}(t+1)$$
$$\implies S=\frac12(2+3+4+\cdots+38)=\frac12\cdot\frac{37}{2}(2+38)=370$$

Comment: Oh yeah, that would do it. There's the trick in this specific case I didn't see. Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

In general, we can prove, by double summation, that
$$
S_n=\sum_{t=1}^n t\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac{1}{t+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)= \frac{n}{4}(n+3)
$$

---

Proof:
\begin{aligned}
S_n & =\sum_{t=1}^n t\left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac{1}{t+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
& =\sum_{t=1}^n \sum_{r=t}^n \frac{t}{r} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{t=1}^r \frac{t}{r} \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r} \sum_{r=1}^r t \\
& =\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{r(r+1)}{2}\\&=\frac{n}{4}(n+3) \end{aligned}

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$S=\sum_{t=1}^{37}t\left(\frac1{t}+\frac1{t+1}+\frac1{t+2}+\cdots+\frac1{37}\right)=\sum_{t=1}^{37}\sum_{k=0}^{37-t}\frac{t}{t+k}$$

and the pattern is

[image]

which leads to

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{37}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac j i=\sum_{i=1}^{37}\frac{i(i+1)}{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^{37}\frac{i+1}{2}=\frac12\left(\frac{37\cdot 38}{2}+37\right)=370$$

Answer (score 1):

This problem was pretty fun. Using the form of the problem
$$
S(n) = \sum_{t=1}^nt(H_n-H_{t-1}) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}H_n-\sum_{t=1}^{n-1}(t+1)H_t = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}H_n-nH_{n-1}-\sum_{t=1}^{n-2}(t+1)H_t
$$
now if we add
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}H_n-nH_{n-1}+\left[\frac{(n-1)n}{2}H_{n-1}-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}H_{n-1}\right]-\sum_{t=1}^{n-2}(t+1)H_t
$$
we end up with
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[H_n-H_{n-1}\right]+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}H_{n-1}-\sum_{t=1}^{n-2}(t+1)H_t.
$$
The identity $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[H_n-H_{n-1}\right]=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and we can see that
$$
\frac{(n-1)n}{2}H_{n-1}-\sum_{t=1}^{n-2}(t+1)H_t = S(n-1)
$$
From here we can conclude that we have the recurrence relation of
$$
S(1)=1
$$
$$
S(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}+S(n-1)
$$

I'll leave it from here to find an explicit formula in terms of $n$ so you can solve for $S(37)$

Comment: With wolframalpha... I found out what S(n) should be...but can you pls give a proof...as I've understood that this problem was beyond my reach...also pls give proofs for the identities you used (even if they're not identities, just some results) pls give proofs...I'm having a hard time understanding each expression you wrote

Comment: Which identity is particularly confusing? I can write up a solution for $S(n)$ in a few hours. All the steps that lead up to the recurrance relation are just algebra so write which ones confuse you and I'll try to give extra justification

Answer (score 1):

In fact, all that’s required is being able to manipulate sums and sum arithmetic sequences. I.e., let $$\chi\left(x,y\right)\ :=\ \begin{cases}1\text{ if }y\geq x\\ 0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and compute
\begin{align*}
    S\ &=\ \sum_{x=1}^{37} x\left(\sum_{y= x}^{37} \frac{1}{y}\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{x=1}^{37} \sum_{y= x}^{37} \frac{x}{y}\\
    &=\ \sum_{x=1}^{37} \sum_{y= 1}^{37} \frac{x}{y}\cdot\chi\left(x,y\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{y=1}^{37} \sum_{x= 1}^{37} \frac{x}{y}\cdot\chi\left(x,y\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{y=1}^{37} \sum_{x= 1}^{y} \frac{x}{y}\\
    &=\ \sum_{y=1}^{37} \frac{1}{y}\left(\sum_{x= 1}^{y} x\right) \\
    &=\ \sum_{y=1}^{37} \frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{y\left(y+1\right)}{2}\\
    &=\ \sum_{y=1}^{37} \frac{y+1}{2}\\
    &=\ \boxed{370}
\end{align*}
(I tried to be as explicit with the steps as possible.)